# DateTime.Now returning the same time several times in a row

Tags: c#, datetime, streamwriter

I'm appending text to an existing TXT file and one of the fields I'm recording the date and time, which are passed to a StreamWriter. The issue I'm having is that using the script a few times in a row is causing the record to come up with the same date and time.

Below is a snippet of what I'm getting as a result and my class just below. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
14/09/2021 8:42:54 PM, nflab, ScriptName, C:\Documents\filename.rvt, 1500
14/09/2021 8:42:54 PM, nflab, ScriptName, C:\Documents\filename.rvt, 1500
14/09/2021 8:42:54 PM, nflab, ScriptName, C:\Documents\filename.rvt, 1500
14/09/2021 8:42:54 PM, nflab, ScriptName, C:\Documents\filename.rvt, 1500
14/09/2021 9:08:21 PM, nflab, ScriptName, C:\Documents\filename.rvt, 1500
14/09/2021 9:08:21 PM, nflab, ScriptName, C:\Documents\filename.rvt, 1500

public static class Usage
{
    readonly static DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
    readonly static string filename = "ScriptUsageLog_";
    readonly static string userName = System.Environment.UserName;
    readonly static string fileExtension = ".txt";
    static string path;

    public static void Log(Document doc, string scriptName, int timeSavings = 0)
    {
        path = doc.PathName;

        using (StreamWriter fileAppend = File.AppendText(FileLocations.UsageFolder +
                                                                       filename +
                                                                       userName +
                                                                       fileExtension))
        {
            fileAppend.WriteLine($"{dateTime}, {userName}, {scriptName}, {path}, {timeSavings}");
            fileAppend.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many times do you think the average computer can get a DateTime.Now in 1 human time second? How tightly are you calling your method? Several times a second?

Comment: try `fileAppend.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} ({DateTime.Now:ffffff}), {userName}, {scriptName}, {path}, {timeSavings}");`

Comment: You may want to format your datetime then to show something more accurate then seconds. It would be good to do formatting here explicitly anyway. Currently your output is presumably culture dependent.

Comment: 1. **Use a proper logging framework** 2. If you need unique timestamps and you write with higher frequency than 1/s, then you need a finer grained timestamp. You could add millis, e.g.

Comment: 3. `readonly static DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;` will pin down the dateTime to one specific instant in time. It's not the same as `readonly static DateTime dateTime => DateTime.Now;`

Comment: Don't forget filesystem actions can be cached so it can be executed in less than a second.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks, good question and I should've added to the original post as many comments were based on that. I was calling it manually, which means there was at least a 10sec delay between calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the global variable `datetime`. This value is set once time when your application started.

*fileAppend.WriteLine($"{**dateTime**}, {userName}, {scriptName}, {path}, {timeSavings}");*

You should update it to

```
fileAppend.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now}, {userName}, {scriptName}, {path}, {timeSavings}");
```

Comment: The OP's results show different values, so I guess this is not really the problem here. I guess they're instanciating the `Usage` class multiple times.

Comment: @XouDo It's all static.

Comment: @Ralf Right. It's unclear how he gets different value then...

Comment: @XouDo as Ralf said, because it's static fields so that these values are not set when create new instance

Comment: @XouDo maybe he has run the app many times and the log is appended.

Comment: And _all that_'s exactly why OP should be using a proper logging framework in the first place.

Comment: @LeVu Thanks, Le. I think you hit the nail on the head. I changed the code as per your recommendation and tried to reproduce the problem without success. I believe you solved it.

Comment: @XouDo Good pickup. I was changing the code, recompiling it and running the program over and over, hence the different times in the records but without restarting the program the time would come up the same.